# Two side by side containers, one stretched

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:
Two side by side containers, the first container has a fixed width, second contaner stretches the entire length of the screen. The second container has a sub-container with a margin, that stretches the entire length of its parent container.

I've achieved this in the following way, but it looks clumsy and I think there's a better way, but I'm drawing a blank. Can you offer a better solution, if one exists?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ack4/

CSS:

```
 .c1 {
        display: table;
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        border:2px solid black;
    }

.c1> div:first-child  {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.c1> div:last-child  {
    display:table-cell;
}

.c1 > div:last-child > div {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}

.c1> div:last-child > div > div {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    top:5px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="c1">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be regarding a specific problem. Maybe better off in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `display: table-cell` is right to go with here.

I used `margin-left` in combination with `float` property.

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/7Ack4/1/)

```
.c1 {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.c1> div:first-child {
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.c1> div:last-child {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
.c1 > div:last-child > div {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
.c1> div:last-child > div > div {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    top:5px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy how much changes in 5 years. In case anyone finds this, here is the simplest solution as of April 2, 2020 - the year of coronavirus.
This is now all you need since flexbox arrived.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child-1">
  </div>

  <div class="child-2">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
  background:blue;
  padding:2px;
  height:40px;
  display:flex;
}
.child-1{
  flex-basis:100px;
  background:green;
}
.child-2{
  background:yellow;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

Here's a codepen.
https://codepen.io/hundredbillion/pen/mdJgYja